# How to specify a cache validator for PNG files in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, last-modified

I would like to cache all images and videos on the website for at least a month at user cache to speed up the loading process.

But the http://gtmetrix.com Speed Report gives me following error:

> The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that
>   do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently.
>   Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for
>   the following resources:
>
> // all *.png files currently on my page listed here //

Expiration times:

```
### CACHING ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
# media: favicon, images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
# htc files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"
# webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
# css and javascript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
```

Cache control:

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|ogg)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
      Header unset Last-Modified
      Header unset ETag
      FileETag None
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
### / CACHING ###
```

What can I do to fix it?

BTW i found this: [htaccess 'Header unset Last-Modified' caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546711/htaccess-header-unset-last-modified-caching-issue) but it looks like the guy doesn't have a problem with images

Answer (score 1):

Given this warning:

> Specify a **Last-Modified** or **ETag** header to enable cache
> validation for the following resource

I suspect these lines in your config is the culprit:

> Header unset **Last-Modified**
>
> Header unset **ETag**
>
> **FileETag** None

Your config is removing the header info used for cache validation.